# Implementing Java code for a betting game on coin-flips

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, compiler-errors

I have looked all over this website and other websites trying to figure how to do this with the knowledge that my teacher has provided me.

Basically the program is supposed to be a user input system where you can make bets on a head or tails coin flipping game.

So far, I've had no luck in what to do. Not asking someone to finish it for me, but to help me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

Here is my code so far:

```html
package Homework6;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.lang.Math;

public class CoinFlip {

 public static void main(String[]args){
 
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 int money = 10;
 double flip = Math.random();
 String heads = "heads";
 String tails = "tails";
 int bet = input.nextInt();
 
 while(bet < 0 || bet > money){
  if(true){
   System.out.println("How much do you want to bet?");
   input.next();
  }
 }
  
 System.out.println("Guess if the coin will be heads or tails.");
 String guess = input.next();
 
 String coin;
 if (flip <0.5) coin = heads;
 else coin = tails;
 
 if(guess == coin){
  int correct = money + bet;
  System.out.println("The flip was"+ coin);
  System.out.println("You win" + bet);
  System.out.println("")
  }
 
 
 
 
 
 }
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question. What exactly are you having trouble with? Where are your issues?

Comment: I would use the random class instead of math.random, in many ways they do the same thing but Random allows you to set a range and will provide you an int, cleaning up your implementation here. Also, though you don't need them for single line if statements, it's good practice to always include braces.

Comment: I don't think your program does do anything except asking user `How much do you want to bet?` . Looks like your `while-loop` will keep asking user same question again and again. Why are you using `if` statement if it's true anyway.

Comment: @UnholySheep I'm sorry I'm just really stressed out over this whole thing.

I feel like I've been on it all day trying to figure it out.

I guess I don't understand what I'm doing wrong in the while loop or my if statements or where to put them really for the intital user input.

 It won't actually print anything anymore with the way I have it set up.

Also, the whole betting system has me really confused. I think I have the coin flipping thing down.

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono the only problem with me using Random is that our teacher hasn't taught us that yet so I don't know how to use it 

and I'm not sure if I can use it my code without him questioning how I learned it.

Comment: @NirajPatel yeah that is also a problem. Because it did do that before i moved some stuff now it wont print anything at all.

I'm just confused on how I should set up my while loop and if statement for it to all work out.

Comment: The 'while loop' seems to be infinite when the first input does not satisfy the 'while-condition', also you are comparing Strings using '=='. Use '.equals()' for comparing String values

Comment: I would suggest you run the while loop till you run out of money or till you reach a target goal of money.

Comment: @Southaw I am pretty sure your teacher understands that the internet exists and that is where you might have found out about Java's Random class. But that's your choice. Also you should print out the values in debug statements to make sure the processes you have doing what you want. That if statement is seriously suspect. I'd revisit that too.

Comment: @a-sir how would I go about setting it up to not be infinite? I've tried putting break in there but it doesn't really do anything especially with the if statement in there

Comment: @Southaw Using a do-while loop for checking if the bet is a valid number would solve this.

Comment: @a-sir whenever I put in the do-while statement. It says my println statement is now unreachable code. which is a problem I was running into earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few notes for you (since you're starting out and still a student):

1) Your while loop is a little bit poorly constructed. That System Out will constantly be printing to the screen until there is some input. And that if statement is essentially doing no conditional checking. It is always true.

2) You never originally prompt the user for how much they want to bet. You're only prompting them after they've input a value. So when you originally hit play, the console is just blank. But really it's waiting for some input.

3) Your if statement for changing the coin state is a little extraneous.

4) The user's amount of money is never actually updated, and the output at the end could be a little more informative.

5) What if someone wins the first one and wants to play again? They probably want to keep that bank growing! So you could encompass the entire thing inside of a do/while that runs while bank > 0.

6) You should only use the `==` operator when comparing primitive types. Pretty much all other times, use `Object.equals(object);`

I know you didn't ask someone to complete it for you, but this site works best by sharing information. Below should work for you, I've commented it extensively. Hopefully this can teach some things beyond just this homework assignment.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Setup some initial variables
    int bank = 10;
    double flip = Math.random();

    // Instantiate a new Scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Let the user bet until they run out of money in the bank
    do
    {
        // Ask the user how much money to wager
        System.out.println("How much do you want to bet?");
        int bet = input.nextInt();

        // The bet was invalid
        while(bet < 0 || bet > bank)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid bet (" + bet + "). Minimum bet = 0. Maximum bet = " + bank);
            bet = input.nextInt();
        }

        // Ask the user for which side
        System.out.println("Heads or tails?");
        String guess = input.next();

        // The coin is either heads or tails, so it can always start as tails. If the value goes under .5, change it to heads. If not, it remains the same, "tails".
        String coin = "tails";
        if (flip < 0.5) 
        {
            coin = "heads";
        }

        // Tell the user the result, regardless of win or lose
        System.out.println("The flip was " + coin);

        // Update the user's bank and inform them of the new value
        if(guess.equalsIgnoreCase(coin)) // this allows for any form of HeaDs or TaILs
        {
            bank += bet;
            System.out.println("You win " + bet);
            System.out.println("Your bank contains " + bank);
        }
        else
        {
            bank -= bet;
            System.out.println("You lose " + bet);
            System.out.println("Your bank contains " + bank);
        }
    }
    while(bank > 0);

    // Goodbye message
    System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");

    // Don't forget to close your Scanner object!
    input.close();  
}
```

Comment: thank you so much!! this looks like exactly what i needed! i really appreciate it!

Comment: i also was looking through my assignment and realized I dont have to use string heads/tails. i can use int 0 or 1 and assign them to heads or tails.

i probably made that really confusing but itll make the program a little easier to write

Comment: @Southpaw can you mark mine for "answered" please?

Comment: sorry about that! I'm still very new to this website

Answer (score 1):

To fix the possible infinite loop:

```
        do{
            System.out.println("How much do you want to bet?");
            bet = input.nextInt();
        }
        while(bet > 0 && bet > money);
```

You can drop the `if` statement since it's not really needed. You will however need to declare the variable `bet` to have the correct scope.

```
if(guess.equals(coin)) // proper way of checking Strings
```

Use this form for checking the value of the guess vs the coin.

Comment: that looks exactly like what i needed for my while loop. I really appreciate it!

I think I can probably work the rest of it out!

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, good luck and lot's of fun learning :D

Answer (score 0):

Alright, since you are having so much trouble with this, I will lay it out how I achieved this.

You need a couple variables, I used these below, taken from your code.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int money = 10;
String heads = "heads";
String tails = "tails";
int bet = 0;
String guess;
String coin;
```

You then need a loop. You have a `while` loop already, and that will do, BUT your conditional is incorrect as I see it. You are testing `bet < 0 || bet > money` which I read as ***"If you bet less than no money or bet more money that you have, enter this loop"*** I believe you want the opposite of that. I also added if you ran out of money.

```
while(bet > 0 || bet < money || money <= 0)
```

Now for the inside of the loop. Here, you want to do a couple things in a certain order.

1. Ask how much they want to bet, read it in the appropriate variable.
2. Ask what their guess is, read it in the appropriate variable.
3. Use your if statement you have to determine if the `flip` was `heads` or `tails`, But I got rid of the `flip` variable, and used `Math.random() < 0.5` directly.
4. Check their guess vs the flip. If they were correct, do what you need to do, i.e. add `bet` to `money` and display some sort of message.
5. If they were wrong, do what you need to do, i.e. subtract bet from money, display some message.

Then your program will start over.

Comment: yeah i figured I wrote it a little goofy with || operator. thank you so much for your help! i really appreciate it! you guys are life savers